# C++ Windows Server - how to accept an SSH connection?

Tags: c++, ssh

I have a server application i'm making specifically for windows. However the client that needs to connect to it was originally created towards a Linux server. The client connects through SSH and runs simple commands to execute bash scripts. I'd like to make my server work with this client without making any changes to the client.

So the client would usually SSH into the Linux server -> run command to execute bash -> bash script did stuff

I'd like the windows server to accept the SSH connection -> grab the command -> execute a function that does what the bash script would of done.

My question here is how can I make my server accept that SSH connection and get that command the client sends through?

Comment: Install OpenSSH via [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these resources will help.

*Set up a free SSH server on Windows 7 with freeSSHd*
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/set-up-a-free-ssh-server-on-windows-7-with-freesshd/

*OpenSSH for Windows*
http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/

*MobaSSH: Free SSH server for Windows*
http://mobassh.mobatek.net/